# What's the preferred way to stop execution in NEAR Rust smart contracts?

Tags: nearprotocol

There are at least 3 methods to stop program execution

1. `panic!`
2. `assert!` (and it's all siblings)
3. `env::panic`

How to properly stop smart contract execution?

Is there any preferred way? When someone should use `env::panic`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They all will eventually call `env::panic`. From the docs [`Terminates the execution of the program with the UTF-8 encoded message.`](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/1.0.0/near_sdk/env/fn.panic.html). It is a wrapper around a host function imported to the contract.

As for the other two, `assert!` checks a boolean and calls `panic!` with a message.
They both support the [fmt::Display](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) trait, which means you can have string interpolation with "{}" marking where a passed string will go in the order of their appearance.

e.g.

```rust
assert!(b, "{}", "oops");
/// is
if (b) {
  panic!("{}", "oops");
}
/// is equivalent to 
if (b) {
  env::panic(format!("{}", "oops"));
}
```

So you can use any one as you see fit.  A great place to see examples of them in the `near-sdk-rs/examples` [like the fungible token contract](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/examples/fungible-token/src/lib.rs).

Comment: What is a "host function"?

Comment: It's a function that the "host" computer provides as an import for the wasm VM.  Here are all of them for a NEAR smart contract: https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/tree/master/near-sdk/src/environment/blockchain_interface.rs